# Using Git to find dates of TODOs

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

I've just started working on a large system. It has a lot of code in it that hasn't been very well looked after. There are over a thousand TODOs scattered about the code (some Java, some Perl, some various other languages), which I found using Intellij IDEA. Also in Intellij, I can annotate a class to find the date that a TODO was committed. Some are over 7 or 8 years old.

Now, I would like to look at the older ones - ones that are, say, over 6 months old.

Is there a way using Git (or IDEA for that matter, or any other tool) to conditionally list any files that contain TODOs based on some criteria (in this case, commit date of the TODO line)?

Edit: Just a further thought - if there is a solution to this, could it also be used to find old comments?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git blame` to see which commit most recently modified each line in a file. Unfortunately, if someone corrects a typo in a line, reindents it line, or has renamed the whole file, `git blame` will report that commit instead of the commit you're looking for. To work around that you'd have to recursively inspect the contents of the parent commit in the same way (taking file renames into account) and attempt to find the same TODO comment. If you find it, recurse once more, and if not you've probably found the commit introducing the comment.

Comment: Can I use `git blame` to tell me which line in a file contains the string `TODO`?

Comment: No, but `grep` can do that.